# Critical CSS Rails: Cannot find css for route

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am using the [Critical CSS rails gem](https://github.com/mudbugmedia/critical-path-css-rails) and I am able to generate the critical css for my `root_path` by calling:

```
CriticalPathCss.generate_all
```

or

```
CriticalPathCss.generate("/")
```

However when I try to fetch the css, it comes back empty:

```
CriticalPathCss.generate_all
=> { "/" => "[data-aos^=fade][data-aos^=fade]{opacity:0}[data-aos=fade
...
}

> CriticalPathCss.fetch("/")
=> ""
```

What am I missing here?  Do I need to manually store it somewhere?

Comment: Have you followed the [usage section in the documentation](https://github.com/mudbugmedia/critical-path-css-rails#usage)?

Comment: yes of course.  Initially my issue was that I use a different caching tool than the standard.  After fixing that, I got it working in development but have had no success with production (on Heroku).

Comment: Oh, in that case try `heroku run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. If that doesn't work, try the same thing but with `assets:clobber` then `precompile`. If it works let me know and I can make this an answer.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with heroku.  Needed to install a different buildpack for puppeteer.